# Using lookahead to find the last character

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to match words that end with "o", "s", "x", "ch" or "sh", but for some reason it's matching any word that has any of these letters.

It's my regex:

```
o|s|x|ch|sh(?=$)
```

Some examples:

- lobster // Should not match
- peach // Should match
- expert // Should not match
- potato // Should match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to group the alternation otherwise it gets interpreted as:

```
o OR s OR x OR ch OR sh(?=$) // pseudo-code
```

You can use a non-capture group to group them together:

```
.*(?:o|s|x|ch|sh)(?=$)
```

And the `.*` allows for the full word to match.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pE9iU0/1)

Comment: Thanks, I just missed the parentheses :)